# Закрыть приложение. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Tabulated Function");
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("table.fxml"));
            rootLayout = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            ControllerTable controllerTable = loader.getController();
            controllerTable.setList(pointsData);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        supportStage = new Stage();
        supportStage.setTitle("Function Parameters: ");
        supportStage.setResizable(false);
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("sample.fxml"));
            startWindow = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(startWindow);
            Controller controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setData(pointsData);
            controller.setStage(supportStage);
            supportStage.setScene(scene);
            supportStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
                supportStage.setIconified(true);
            });
            supportStage.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

сначало запускается основное приложение, потому вспомогательное, в котором вводятся данные и добавляются в основное, есть 2 проблемы:
1) Когда нажимаешь кнопку закрыть в основном окне, программа должна прекращать работу, но остается вспомогательное окно.
2) Когда нажимаешь кнопку закрыть во вспомогательном окне, оно просто должно сворачивать, но оно закрывается.

Comment: Честно не вижу кнопок у вас в коде но поверю на слово... Переопределите метод стоп у чаилда... И добавте для полноты картины ссылку родителя ребенку... Вешайте слушателя на состояние и реагируйте на закрытие...

Comment: supportStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            supportStage.setIconified(true);
            System.exit(0);
        });

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на первый вопрос

> 1) Когда нажимаешь кнопку закрыть в основном окне, программа должна
>   прекращать работу, но остается вспомогательное окно

```
supportStage.initOwner(primaryStage)
```

Ответ на второй вопрос

> 2) Когда нажимаешь кнопку закрыть во вспомогательном окне, оно просто
>   должно сворачивать, но оно закрывается

```
supportStage.setOnCloseRequest(event - > {
     supportStage.setIconified(true);
     event.consume();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы, не использовать Модальное окно?

Например:

```
private Stage mainStage;
private Parent fxmlEdit;
private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
private EditDialogController editDialogController;
private Stage editDialogStage;

private void initLoader(){
    try {
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("edit.fxml"));
        fxmlEdit = fxmlLoader.load();
        editDialogController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showDialog() {
    if (editDialogStage == null) {
        editDialogStage = new Stage();
        editDialogStage.setTitle("Title");
        editDialogStage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlEdit));
        editDialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        editDialogStage.initOwner(mainStage);
    }
    editDialogStage.showAndWait();
}
```

При этом, доступ к основному окну будет закрыт. И вы спокойно можете получить данные с контроллера Модального Окна. Или может я не правильно понял суть вспомогательного окна?